# What kind of encoding is this (not base64)?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, base64, json

Recently, I'm working with an API which has response code similar to this:

P257SIae5AEchhrQy6

I've tried base64 and doesn't seem like it. Any clue? I think it could be some sort of base64 because sometimes it has this ending " VEPJlm/a2cDz9JMY+ignA=  " which uses = to fill up space.

edit:

NjFpSYZO7LQByUEhBVWKR6R69DLVKdJxvC+PfsQAvdkADzYl/P257SIae5AEchhrQy6/Gx2FCtHP7ykVmc6kHQRczgq3WF3AvNAHuPsMeXphjWbHGUGyuEz5Jd4QD9xt0UdZVFt/tQW6+l+CkSA3U1CwsV8n787tB+t/XbB42F57k1LpT39OUYTvRS4lbnq3

Comment: This may be a unique id. Without looking at the API you are using, I don't think so we can predict the encoding used here. I suggest you dive into the documentation of your API so that you may get some clues.

Comment: By the way, why do you claim it is not Base64? You sample string is perfect standard Base64 string, and often trailing "=" are not emited.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be any encoding. Just a unique id.

Comment: Hi Jeff, it is not an unique string because this is a callback:  NjFpSYZO7LQByUEhBVWKR6R69DLVKdJxvC+PfsQAvdkADzYl/P257SIae5AEchhrQy6/Gx2FCtHP7ykVmc6kHQRczgq3WF3AvNAHuPsMeXphjWbHGUGyuEz5Jd4QD9xt0UdZVFt/tQW6+l+CkSA3U1CwsV8n787tB+t/XbB42F57k1LpT39OUYTvRS4lbnq3

Comment: It looks quite like base64 but the online decoder doesn't seem to work. Could it be something else + base64?

Comment: A lot of times people "seed" text with a randon bit pattern and then base 64 decode it.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably Base64 encoded binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this over a serial line? May be a mismatched baudrate, parity, data/stop bit or flow control handshake problem.